# Get the current value of a visualforce field

Tags: visualforce

I have a VisualForce input text box:

```
            <apex:inputText value="{!Address1}" id="Example1TextBox" html-placeholder="Example 1"/><br></br>
```

In the controller class I have:

```
public string Address1{
    get{
        Id myId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        FedExLabelMethods job = new FedExLabelMethods();
        String AddressValue;
        List<String> compressedAddresses = FedExLabelMethods.getlistofAddresses(myId);
        for(integer i=0; i < compressedAddresses.size(); i++){
            String temp = compressedAddresses[i];
            if(temp.contains(returnAddressesValue)){
                string[] temparray = temp.split(',');
                AddressValue = temparray[1];
                AddressValue = AddressValue.substring(1);
                i = i + 10000000;
            } else {
            }
        }
        if (AddressValue == 'null'){
            AddressValue = '';
        }
        return AddressValue;
    }
    set;
}
```

Which is referencing a select list. Essentially the textbox will display a query value for whatever the selectlist has currently selected.  However I have a problem:  If the select list has nothing selected, or even if it does have something selected, and I want to change the value of the text box **manually**, then when the form is re-rendered it references the selectlist again and deletes whatever is in it to comply to the code.

Essentially, the text box only listens to the selectlist, whereas I want it to be somewhat like:

IF the textbox has text in it, THEN ignore the query and just set the text that is currently in it.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:  By the way, the selectlist rerenders the form but I'm figuring i'll need to either add an actionsupport to the textbox to rerender the form or a button, I'm fine with either one.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you want to make your code more readable and shorter, you can use the 'foreach' syntax (`for (String temp: compressedAddresses)`), remove the 'else' block, and instead of doing `i + 10000000` (*very* ugly), just use `break;`

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the get section of the string:

```
if(Address1 != null){
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Address1',Address1);
            AddressValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Address1');
```

then put all of the current code in the else statement and return the addressvalue!

Make sure to check and see if the selectlist is custom

Answer (score 0):

I would use this address value inside a javascript block on the page and use it to fill the value of the input IF needed. ie:

```
<script>

    var address1 = '{!Address1}';
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
    var inputElement = inputElements[0];
    //you will have to verify that this works - this is just example code

    if (!inputElement.value){
        inputElement.value = address1;
    }
</script>
```

You can make sure this gets rerendered also by putting it in the page in an apex element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does help but I ended up doing what my answer is below.

Comment: Looks like a good solution